# Low temperature flexible polymers

Tags: materials

I'm working on a design project that will require a flexible component that will be operating at temperatures from $0^{\circ}$C to $-200^{\circ}$C. Are there any thermoplastic polymers that remain flexible at the lower thermal extreme?

If the temperature range was closer to near zero I would just use silicone tubing, but the lower limit for silicone seems to be around $-70^{\circ}$C to $-50^{\circ}$C typically.

Comment: Does it have to be a thermoplastic?

Comment: Have you checked the data sheets or contacted manufacturers?

Comment: @EricS, I suppose it doesn't have to be a theromplastic. Ideally it would be for forming purposes. Metals would be ideal for the temperature range (thermal contraction aside) and I've been working under the assumption that injection molding was likely going to be used. Thermosets I suppose could be used as well though?

Comment: @SolarMike I've pulled the data sheets for all the available materials that I can think of. And of the suppliers I've talked to "we'll get back to you" seems to be the flavor of the month with no follow up. I was hoping for some thoughts on alternatives that I wasn't aware of.  I've just discovered (since the original post) that matweb has a property search feature that I never knew about (so cool!) That is looking promising.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of elastomers since you mentioned it needs to be flexible. It isn’t clear how flexible that is.